# how can we remove comma from specific column using sed

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

The PSQL table values are

```
select * from A;

2017-04-30 08:51:17.833084  A 12  Invalid digit, Value 'U', Pos 0, Type: Long                                                                                                                                                                                
2017-04-30 08:51:17.833083  A 11  Invalid digit, Value 'U', Pos 0, Type: Long
2017-04-30 08:51:17.833082  A 10  Invalid digit, Value 'U', Pos 0, Type: Long
```

The issue is when I tried to get this output to csv format like -o output.csv

the last column value splitting to Invalid digit-4th column Value 'U'-- 5th column Pos 0 --6th column Type: Long --7 th column due to ',' char is there in the column. so i want to remove comma from last column
my expected output is

```
col1                      col2 col3            col4
2017-04-30 08:51:17.833084  A 12  Invalid digit Value 'U' Pos 0 Type: Long                                                                                                                                                                                
2017-04-30 08:51:17.833083  A 11  Invalid digit Value 'U' Pos 0 Type: Long
2017-04-30 08:51:17.833082  A 10  Invalid digit Value 'U' Pos 0 Type: Long
```

my command is:

```
"select * from values;" | sed -e "s/,/-/g"  >> outputfile.csv
```

but it changes all columns

Comment: Better do it on database level, Change your select query to `select col1,col2,col3,replace(col4,',','-') as col4 from values;`

Comment: Also if you want to do in Unix, then you have to define the delimiter. In the example you gave, there are many `spaces` so you cannot use space as a delimiter. How are you planning to address that.

Comment: also, you said that you wanted *to remove **comma** from last column* - but your expected output has no commas at all

Comment: yes . i dont want comma in last column as my output format is csv

Comment: That utsav. its working  as expected now. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, it is better to resolve it at Database level, as your delimiter is looking like `space`, which will give you incorrect result. So your select query will be:

```
select col1,col2,col3,replace(col4,',','-') as col4 from values
```

Edit: As suggested by Ed, you can hardcode `comma` as delimiter and replace comma from forth column, in a single select clause as well. Something like

```
select col1||','||col2||','||col3||','||replace(col4,',','-') from values
```

If you absolutely want to handle it in Unix, then assuming that the delimiter is `tab` character, use something like below. (I am not sure that is default delimiter, but you can change it by using `set colsep |` to set delimiter to pipe). The answer below assumes `tab` as delimiter.

```
awk -F"\t" '{ gsub(",","-",$4); print $0}'
```

Edit: As per Ed, `this would replace all tabs (FSs) with single blank chars (OFSs) - you'd need this instead`

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {gsub(/,/,"-",$4)} 1'
```

Comment: That utsav. its working  as expected now. thanks a lot

Comment: If it worked for you, the accept the answer by checking the `tick` on left of the answer. So the question could be closed.  Also I see that you have many previous open questions. Close them too my accepting the best answer.

Comment: `+1` for the `select` approach but is there no option for `select` to enclose the output "columns" in double quotes and specify the column-separator character as `,`? The `awk` script, btw would replace all tabs (`FS`s) with single blank chars (`OFS`s) - you'd need this instead: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {gsub(/,/,"-",$4)} 1'`

Comment: specify column-separator as comma in select clause is a better option. And thanks for the tip on `awk`. I would edit the answer to accommodate both to it.

Comment: @EdMorton - What is the `1` at the end of `awk` command for? True?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, `1` (or any non-zero number or any non-null string) is a true condition which causes awk to perform the default action of printing the current record. It's a very common awk idiom used in small scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got the propose of your question. But if you want to got rid of every last `,` in every line and you have to do this with sed, try this:

```
$ cat file
2017-04-30 08:51:17.833084  A 12  Invalid digit, Value 'U', Pos 0, Type: Long
2017-04-30 08:51:17.833083  A 11  Invalid digit, Value 'U', Pos 0, Type: Long
2017-04-30 08:51:17.833082  A 10  Invalid digit, Value 'U', Pos 0, Type: Long
$
$ sed 's/\(^[0-9]*.*Pos\s[0-9]\)\(,\)\(.*$\)/\1\3/g' file
2017-04-30 08:51:17.833084  A 12  Invalid digit, Value 'U', Pos 0 Type: Long
2017-04-30 08:51:17.833083  A 11  Invalid digit, Value 'U', Pos 0 Type: Long
2017-04-30 08:51:17.833082  A 10  Invalid digit, Value 'U', Pos 0 Type: Long
```

What is sed doing in this case?

We use sed's global `g` substitution `s` command `s/regex/pattern/g`.
The pattern are elements of the three regex-groups `\(regex\)`,
here the first `\1` and the last `\3`.
The second regex-group, here your `,`, is `\(,\)`, will be omitted in the replacement.